# How to check if Meteor.call() fails when server connection is down?

Tags: meteor

When the Meteor server connection is lost, how can I verify that Meteor.call() failed? Meteor.call() doesn't return any value. Basically Ctrl+Z in the Meteor shell when your app is running, then do something in the app that triggers a Meteor.call i.e. adding a new blog post:

```
Meteor.call('createPhrase', phrase, function(error) {
  console.log("This NEVER gets called if server is down.");

  if (error) {
     throwError(error.reason);
  }
});
```

I tried using Session vars, but the reactivity screws it up, i.e. the code below will trigger an error in my template handler (that get's flashed to the browser quickly) and as soon as isMyError is set to true, then when the Meteor.call is successful the error goes away as per isMyError = false, but this looks really sloppy.

```
Session.set("isMyError", true);

Meteor.call('createPhrase', phrase, function(error) {
   console.log("This NEVER gets called if server is down.");

   Session.set("isMyError", false);

    if (error) {
        throwError(error.reason);
    }
});


Template.index.isMeteorStatus = function () {

   myClientStatus = Meteor.status();

   if ( (myClientStatus.connected === false) || (Session.get("isMyError") === true) ) {
     return false;
   } else {
     return true;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meteor's calls are generally entered into a queue that are sent to the server in the order that they are called. If there is no connection they stay in the queue until the server is connected once more.

This is the reason nothing is returned because Meteor hopes that it can reconnect then send the call and when it does it does eventually return a result then.

If you want to validate whether the server is connected at the point of the call it's best to check `Meteor.status().connected` (which is reactive) and only run `Meteor.call` if it is else throw an error

```
if(Meteor.status().connected)
    Meteor.call(....
else throwError("Error - not connected");
```

You could also use `navigator.onLine` to check whether the network is connected.

The reason you would experience a 60 second delay with `Meteor.status().connected` on the true status of whether meteor is connected or not is there isn't really a way for a browser to check if its connected or not.

Meteor sends a periodic heartbeat, a 'h' on the websocket/long polling wire to check it is connected. Once it realizes it didn't get a heartbeat on the other end it marks the connection disconnected.

However, it also marks it as disconnected if a `Meteor.call` or some data is sent through and the socket isn't able to send any data. If you use a `Meteor.call` beforehand to `Meteor.status().connected` it would realize much sooner that it is disconnected. I'm not sure it would realize it immediately that you can use them one line after the next, but you could use a `Meteor.setTimeout` after a second or two to fire the call.

#### Attempt to succeed:

Meteor is designed very well to attempt to succeed. Instead of 'attempting to fail' with an error stating the network is not available its better to try and queue everything up until the connection is back.

The best thing to do would be to avoid telling the user the network is down because usually they would know this. The queued tasks ensure the userflow would be unchanged as soon as the connection is back.

So it would be better to work with the queues that are built into the reconnection process rather than to avoid them.

Comment: that makes sense, but this post here is what started this whole Meteor.call thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925528/meteor-status-not-showing-lost-connection-when-client-writes-to-server-code Meteor.status() let's 60 seconds pass before the user know's there is an issue. Any clues, mucho gracias.

Comment: And what if the network connection doesn't come back until after the user reboots their machine? Will anything get queued then? The issue with the queued tasks is they don't update the templates reactively since the meteor.call hasn't changed the collection. And putting all the DB insert / update code on the client seems like a security risk and also a lot more bits for the client to download.

Comment: @GiantElk but how would this be any different from a normal web session it would act the same way? There is a project out there called meteor-offline data that can take care of storing it during the reboot. Anyway as I mentioned you can use `navigator.onLine` if you really want to do it the way you suggested.

Comment: a normal web session doesn't try and cue calls to the server, it fails right away, and your browser shows an error. I've never heard of navigator.onLine what is that? I don't want to store changes offline, I just want a decent error message.

Comment: `navigator.onLine` returns true or false from the web browser on whether the operating system has access to the internet : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine

Comment: I prefer meteor's behavior because it attempts to succeed over attempting to fail. User's don't like seeing error messages they just want their stuff to work. This is about what you want your app to behave like though because that is what building apps is about, design is all down custom! I believe `navigator.onLine` would be mre helpful than Meteor's own `status().connected` as used in the answer above